# Intercept private methods with Spring and AspectJ

Tags: java, spring, aop, aspectj, spring-boot

I am trying to execute code before a private method using AspectJ's load-time-weaving with Spring-Boot and annotation-based configuration and I'm pulling my hair out trying to figure out why my aspect is not being invoked.

My simple aspect is as follows:

```
@Aspect
public class LoggingAspect {

  private static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggingAspect.class);

  @Before("execution(private * com.mycompany.MyServiceWithPrivateMethods.*(..))")
  public void privateAspect() {
    log.warn("#### Private method aspect invoked!");
  }

}
```

I also have the `@EnableLoadTimeWeaving` annotation on my Spring configuration class and the following in my META-INF/aop.xml:

```
<aspectj>    
    <weaver options="-verbose">
        <!-- only weave classes in our application-specific packages -->
        <include within="com.mycompany.*"/>
    </weaver>

    <aspects>
        <!-- weave in just this aspect -->
        <aspect name="com.mycompany.LoggingAspect"/>
    </aspects>    
</aspectj>
```

Lastly, I am also starting my application with the `-javaagent:/path/to/spring-instrument.jar` option, per the docs.  I also have the required jars on my classpath (`spring-aop` and `aspectjweaver`) as also mentioned in the Spring docs.

Is this even possible? There is a 'limitation' listed in the AspectJ docs that states `Privileged aspects are not supported by the annotation style.` located [here](http://eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/next/adk15notebook/ataspectj-aspects.html), however [this](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/aop/44790-spring-aop-caching-with-aspectj-weaving-is-not-happening) older post in the Spring Forum seems to indicate that it is indeed possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would have thought it would work, but I would have also thought you would have to add aspectjweaver.jar as a javaagent. One of those assumptions is wrong?

Comment: Hi Dave, thanks for the response.  I added `aspectjweaver.jar` as an additional `-javaagent` option and it looks like it is weaving correctly now.  According to the my interpretation of the Spring ref manual (section 8.8.4) I would think I only needed spring-instrument.jar.  Can you explain why I need both?  (It won't work with `aspectjweaver.jar` as the solve `-javaagent`, either.)

Comment: Make that 'sole' `-javaagent`