# Spring AspectJ Integration Not Working

Tags: java, spring, spring-aop

I am attempting to use the Spring/AspectJ integration with no luck. Spring version is 3.2.17 (yes, a bit old, I know).

Here is my relevant configuration:

pom.xml:

```
    <!-- Spring dependencies, including spring-aspects -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.4</version>
    </dependency>
```

applicationContext.xml:

```
<context:annotation-config/>
<aop:aspectj-autoproxy />
<bean id="loggingAspect" class="com.jason.app.web.util.logging.LoggingAspect" />
```

LoggingAspect.java (relevant class):

```
@Aspect
public class LoggingAspect {

    private Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggingAspect.class);


    /**
     * Advice for before logging
     * @param joinPoint
     */
    @Before("execution(* com.jason.app.web.process..*(..))")
    private void beforeAdvice(JoinPoint joinPoint) {

        final String outputFormat = "intercept: executing method %s(%s)";
        final String method =joinPoint.getSignature().getName();

        List<?> argumentList = Collections.unmodifiableList(Arrays.asList(joinPoint.getArgs()));
        final String formattedArguments = argumentList.stream().map(s -> s.toString()).collect(Collectors.joining(", "));

        log.debug(String.format(outputFormat, method, formattedArguments));

    }
}
```

I've pour over online tutorials, no luck. Can anyone point out what I did wrong?

Jason

Comment: Closing this because the moderators convinced themselves I wanted to use Spring-AOP, when I was trying to discuss Spring integration with AspectJ due to the limitations of Spring-AOP.

Thanks for nothing guys.

Answer (score 2):

The Spring configuration tag `<aop:aspectj-autoproxy />` will enable Spring's proxy based AOP infrastructure, which only applies to Spring beans, and it does so using proxies with all the limitations of this solution compared to a pure AspectJ one.

Now if you want to go with AspectJ instead of Spring AOP, you will need to choose between compile-time weaving or load-time weaving. If you go with compile-time weaving, you need to add the [aspectj-maven-plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/aspectj-maven-plugin/) to your build. If you choose load-time-weaving, you'll need to run your JVM with a `-javaagent:path/to/aspectjweaver.jar` vm argument, as documented in [AspectJ Documentation](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/devguide/ltw-configuration.html).

If you need to make your aspect post-processed by Spring (autowiring, etc), you need to list it in your Spring configuration. Aspects are singleton instances created outside of Spring, so you need to specify the static factory method `aspectOf()` to acess the single instance of the aspectj created by the AspectJ runtime.

```
<bean id="loggingAspect" 
    class="com.jason.app.web.util.logging.LoggingAspect" 
    factory-method="aspectOf"
/>
```

or the annotated way:

```
@Configuration
public class AspectConfig {
    @Bean
    public LoggingAspect loggingAspect() {
        return LoggingAspect.aspectOf();
    }
}
```

Don't forget to remove `<aop:aspectj-autoproxy />` if you're not planning to use Spring AOP in addition to AspectJ. And why would you choose to do so, when AspectJ is so much more powerful?

Comment: THANK YOU. It seems like most of the Spring/AspectJ tutorials left this out. Spring AOP will not meet my needs as I need to log entry and output of all methods, not just public ones.

Answer (score 1):

you could add one more dependency

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

try, changing your point cut to

```
@Before("execution(* com.jason.app.web.process..*.*(..))")
```

( means advice will be applied to all public methods  defined in the service package or a sub-package: com.jason.app.web.process )

Comment: Still nothing. Do I have to enable compile-time weaving or use the aspectj maven plugin?

My problem is that I have a requirement to log entry and results of ALL method calls, regardless of access specifier. So, Spring AOP won't work since it's proxy-based and can only do public methods.

Comment: @Jason they you have to go for pure aspectJ. as you said spring can only intercept public methods 
check http://stackoverflow.com/q/23327336/410677

Comment: That's why I was saying AspectJ and not Spring AOP.

Answer (score 0):

change the expression to 
 `@Before("execution(public * your.package.YourClass.yourMethod(..))")`